# no ROC curve is plotting with geom_roc()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use geom_roc() on my R, but nothing is plotting. There is no error messages, and the grid of the ROC curve is shows up, but I don't see any graph on the grid.
Could you tell me how to fix this problem? Thank you,

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(plotROC)
df1 <- data.frame(read.csv(file="DogData.csv", header=TRUE, sep=","))
df1
df1$Status.Cancer <- as.factor(df1$Status.Cancer)
df1$Status.SIRS <- as.factor(df1$Status.SIRS)
df1$Status.Sepsis <- as.factor(df1$Status.Sepsis)
ggplot(df1, aes(d = Status.Cancer, m = AGE)) + geom_roc()
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - are you asking, as your title suggests, *how* to adjust data, or are you asking *whether* to adjust data? Clarifying what you want, and also showing any attempts you've tried to answer your own question will help you get better responses. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on producing a question that people can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the problem. The problem was that Status.Cancer wasn't specified as numeric column.
Change the column into numeric type and everything works just fine.